# How to print iterable in one line regardless of the python version?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

We use python 2 and 3 on different computers. I would like to print iterable in one line without changing the print line, i.e. not to be dependent on the version. As an example, I would like to have something like:

```
     import sys

     for i in range(101):        
        if int(sys.version[0]) == 2: 
            print i,    
        else: 
            print(i, end = ' ')
```

but without error messages because of the version specific issue. There must be a simple solution. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: That works: from __future__ import print_function and print(i, end = ' ').  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exec` to keep the interpreter from checking for syntax errors at the start of the script, like this:

```
import sys

for i in range(101):
    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
        exec("print i,")
    elif sys.version_info.major == 3:
        exec("print(i, end=' ')")
```

Comment: Please note that if you are going to use `exec` you should only ever ever ever pass in a hard coded string as the parameter. It is an insanely unsafe function to use.